# Half-integer Spin and "natural conformal dimension"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, conformal-field-theory, field-theory

If we consider a classical field theory for a massless particle of integer spin $s$, in a curved space-time, one finds that it is "naturally" conformal in a space-time of dimension $2+2s$

For instance,  the free massless scalar field theory is conformal in $2$ dimensions,  the electromagnetic field theory is conformal in $4$ dimensions, etc...

But does it work for half-integer spin, for instance is a spin $\frac{1}{2}$ field theory conformal in a $3$ dimensional space-time , and is a spin $\frac{3}{2}$ field theory conformal in a $5$ dimensional space-time  ?

Comment: I think even the examples that are in 'etc.' are wrong. spin-2 (I mean Einstein equations or linearization thereof) is not conformal in $d=6$. Conformal gravity is something very different from the usual one. In $6d$ the conformally invariant equations for spin-two have $6$ derivatives for example. Free scalar is conformal in any dimension, by the way

Comment: @John : The theories I am speaking about is field theory in a curved space-time, so, for a free field, you have actions like$\mathcal S = \int d^D x \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu\phi \partial_\nu\phi$, and for a spin 2 field, you have terms like $\mathcal S = \int d^D x \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu} g^{\lambda\rho}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\mu \phi_{\lambda \alpha} \partial_\nu \phi_{\rho \beta}$. Now, if you make a transformation $g_{\mu\nu} \to \lambda g_{\mu\nu}$, you have $\sqrt{-g} \to \lambda^{D/2} \sqrt{-g}$, and $g^{\mu\nu} \to \lambda^{-1} g^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: @John :.... So it is easy to see that scalar field theory is conformal in $D=2$, while a spin-2 field theory is conformal in $D=6$

Comment: it is not called conformal, this is about simple rescaling by a constant, which has nothing to do with $so(d,2)$, i.e. with conformal group. Again, free scalar is conformal in any $d$.

Comment: @John : $\lambda$ is not a constant, it is a function $\lambda(x)$, that is $g_{\mu\nu}(x) \to \lambda(x) g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

Comment: ok, then it is called Weyl symmetry and not conformal. You cannot put arbitrary spin field on a curved background by the way, with the exception of lower spin fields. They will lose gauge invariance and hence cannot be massless

Comment: @John : Seems correct. But there are relations between the two (Weyl and conformal). For instance, in  $d  > 2$ dimensions , if we admit a theory with is invariant under Weyl transformations and diffeomorphic transformations, its restriction to Minkowski space is $SO(2,d)$ invariant, see  this interesting [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.4362v6.pdf). Of course, for $d=2$, the conformal group is infinite, so it is not $SO(2,2)$

Comment: Ok, but the question is formally not even wrong because you cannot put spin-s field on a general gravitational background. Flat space or (A)dS spaces are the only allowed

Comment: @John : And I don't think at all that (Klein-Gordon) scalar fields, without a coupling term with the scalar curvature, are conformal invariant in dimension $d \neq 2$, see this precedent [PSE post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90841/6316)

Comment: yes, yes coupling term, everyone knows. so, it is conformally invariant in arbitrary d. And this question cannot even be asked for a field of high-spin on general background

Comment: @John : OK, so my question was not precise enough, my fault. I meant explicitely without coupling to scalar curvature or Ricci tensor.

Comment: The question is not precise because there exist no massless particle of spin-s (s>2) on general backrounds.